# HttpClient gets timeout

Tags: c#, .net, bots, timeout, dotnet-httpclient

I have a bot (`console application .NET 8`) which run twice a month for 24-48 hours each time.
I make 3-4 get/post requests per second and the whole purpose of this bot is to be fast as it can be and stable - 30 seconds of delay/stuck can make this running to be a big failure.

So the timeout I've set is 5 seconds: `HttpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)`.

I have got some timeout but it not very often - 4-5 timeout occurs in a whole running (+24h), and in case of timeout I retry again after 0.5s delay, in case it fails as well, the whole loop and flow start from scratch.

Lately I added `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` and replaced `HttpClientHandler` with `SocketsHttpHandler` for better performance but then I start to receive many timeouts one after one which make the bot to be unavailable since the flow could not start but just failed with timeout again and again, so I undo my changes and still receive a lot of timeouts, I back to previous version in git and still have a lot of timeouts - so it was just a coincidence? :)

I increased the timeout to be a `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6)` but still.
It sounds like it an issue with the target website, but the wierd thing is that via broswer the same flow works normaly while from httpClient it fails (the same time the bot gives error, I actual entering the broswer and it works).
So I have cases that for few minutes the bot isn't running, or get a failure and then it's ok.

What can be the reasons for that (receive a timeout using `HttpClient`, work from broswer very fast)? - the important thing it works perfectly until last week.
Abuse the server isn't relevant or rate limiting and stuff like that.
I don't use a proxy because there is no need for it plus the fact with the most expensive proxy I found, latency is too long for my purpose.

I don't want to increase the timeout to be longer because it better to restart the flow after retry than wait for a timeout 30s or more.

```
private void CreateClient()
{
    cookies = new CookieContainer();
    clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookies }; // This was until now HttpClientHandler, but few days ago changed into SocketHttpHandler - doesn't change anything
    client = new HttpClient(clientHandler) { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6) }; 
}

private async Task MainMethodAsync()
{
    // each iteration is about 4-5 seconds and I have total 14 requets per iteration
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            ..
            ..
            ..
            var requestResult = await RequestAsync();
            ..
            ..
            var requestResult1 = await RequestPostAsync();
            var requestResult2 = await RequestPost2Async();
            ..
            ..
            
            if(someCondition) // -> can be after 24 hours or more
                break;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //log it and swallow
        }
    }
}


private async Task<string> RequestAsync()
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "url"))
    {
        request.Headers.Add("SomeHeader", "SomeHeader");
        ..
        ..
        request.Headers.Add("SomeHeader2", "SomeHeader2");
        
        using var responseMessage = await RetrySendAsync(request);
        var response = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return response;
    }
}


// This method used for POST and GET as well so content is an optional
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RetrySendAsync(
    HttpRequestMessage request,
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> content = null)
{
    var currentAttempt = 1;
    var delay = 500;
    var result = (HttpResponseMessage)null;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            if (content != null)
                request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(content);

            result = await client.SendAsync(request); // --> currently without HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead
            
            break;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex) // --> timeouts
        {
            throw new OperationCanceledException(ex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (currentAttempt == MaxAttempts)
                throw new Exception(ex);

            await Task.Delay(delay);
            delay *= 2;
            currentAttempt++;
            request = request.CloneRequest(); //I clone the request to avoid "the request already sent" error
        }
    } while (currentAttempt <= MaxAttempts);
    return result;
}

public void Dispose()
{
    client.Dispose();
    clientHandler.Dispose();
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

Comment: I'd say, try replicating exact browser request with extra headers, user-agent etc and see what happens. If the service you're calling is not your own, there might be some extra filters along the way you are not aware of.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. First when I built the bot, that's exactly what I did - I followed Fiddler and replicated the exact request. each header include user-agent and all others - that's the only way I succeed to manage the desire logic I want. Only after I replicate it 100% it was work for me.. but now something has been changed. However, I don't think it's request related since in 24hours of running I get lets say 100-150 timeouts, all other requests (thousands) are works. It just look unstable.